# Bootstrap Footer sits correctly when on Desktop, but moves above content on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a website, but having trouble with the footer.

Footer should sit below content. Not sticky - it should be scrolled to. 
On desktop it sits fine, however on a mobile device (or narrow viewport) it will go above main content.

basic html structure

```
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <main>
    <row>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </row>
    <row>
      <div class="container-fluid col-sm-6"></div>
      <div class="container-fluid col-sm-6"></div>
    </row>
  </main>
  <row></row>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

relevant css

```
main {
  height:97%;
  position: relative;   
  font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
}

footer {
  background-color: #5fc3eb;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2em;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  height: 5em;
  position: relative;
}
```

You can dig around the troublesome site at [amiec.com.au](http://amiec.com.au).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing / Commenting the html "height:97%"  will do the trick. In your CSS, height is also applying on html tag as well[image]

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template), like change:

- `<main>` to `<main class="container">`
- `<row>` to `<div class="row">`

Demo of my thought: https://jsfiddle.net/g3tr7kut/

Answer (score 0):

Find that,

[image]

As per your code , set `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` ..

Note: Remember one thing I'm telling you to change bootstrap default css just because you write this code like that ..